# redis "10000 changes in 60 seconds" is running only every 3 minutes

Tags: redis

I'm investigating redis memory issues on our system.

I'm trying to figure out what are the 10000 changes that are made (it is too many in my opinion)

The weird thing is that I'm getting `10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...` but every 3 minutes and not 60 seconds as I would have expected.

Log sample:

```
[10993] 03 Jan 06:37:46.166 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[10993] 03 Jan 06:37:46.167 * Background saving started by pid 4802
[4802] 03 Jan 06:37:46.170 * DB saved on disk
[4802] 03 Jan 06:37:46.170 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[10993] 03 Jan 06:37:46.268 * Background saving terminated with success
[10993] 03 Jan 06:40:27.140 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[10993] 03 Jan 06:40:27.141 * Background saving started by pid 5081
[5081] 03 Jan 06:40:27.145 * DB saved on disk
[5081] 03 Jan 06:40:27.145 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[10993] 03 Jan 06:40:27.242 * Background saving terminated with success
[10993] 03 Jan 06:43:08.335 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
```

redis_version:2.8.4

Comment: it's not exactly 3 minutes, more like 2.6 minutes. that's probably when 1000 changes are reached and redis persists.Try using `MONITOR` to see what's going on.

Comment: Could you post the configuration file of your redis instance (at least the part which is relevant)?

Comment: The save is:
 save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000

I was just wondering why it prints 60 seconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`save 60 10000` in your config means that redis periodically checks if there has been at least 10000 changes **and** its been **at least** 60 seconds since the last rdb save. Only when both of these conditions are met (for any of your save points) does a new rdb save start.

Also, if you think 10000 changes in ~3min sounds like a lot, don't forget that one command can increase the change count by more than one, e.g. `MSET`.

Comment: The log would probably make to sense if it read `10000 changes and >60 seconds since last save. Saving...`

Answer (score 2):

This is copied from the **redis.conf** file and it explains everything.

```
################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
#
# Save the DB on disk:
#
#   save <seconds> <changes>
#
#   Will save the DB if both the given number of seconds and the given
#   number of write operations against the DB occurred.
#
#   In the example below the behaviour will be to save:
#   after 900 sec (15 min) if at least 1 key changed
#   after 300 sec (5 min) if at least 10 keys changed
#   after 60 sec if at least 10000 keys changed
#
#   Note: you can disable saving completely by commenting out all "save" lines.
#
#   It is also possible to remove all the previously configured save
#   points by adding a save directive with a single empty string argument
#   like in the following example:
#
#   save ""

save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

If you want to see all the activities use the command **monitor**

```
$ redis-cli monitor
1339518083.107412 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "keys" "*"
1339518087.877697 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "dbsize"
1339518090.420270 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "set" "x" "6"
1339518096.506257 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
1339518099.363765 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "del" "x"
1339518100.544926 [0 127.0.0.1:60866] "get" "x"
```